# "Error converting data type varchar to float" from a single line file import

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having trouble converting to float. Here is the code:

```
DECLARE @USRATE as varchar(10);

SELECT @USRATE = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'file.txt', SINGLE_NCLOB) rate_from_file;

PRINT @USRATE;
PRINT CAST(@USRATE AS float);
PRINT CONVERT(FLOAT, @USRATE);
```

The txt file is simply a decimal value (i.e 0.8000 followed by carriage return) but both of the above commands returns:

```
0.7883
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 9
Error converting data type varchar to float.
```

So both CAST and CONVERT don't work. I also tried converting to DECIMAL with the same output. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hence, the `@usrate` has characters that are not recognized as valid digits.  It is quite possible that the end of line is interfering with the conversion.  You might try:

```
select cast(left(@usrate, 6) as float)
```

By the way, there is an argument that you should be converting to a decimal rather than a float, to avoid issues around floating point precision.

Comment: Sir, you made my day! That worked perfectly :)
I will take note of the precision argument you mention. Thank you!